# MariaDB / Sequelize SQL syntax error when syncing

Tags: mariadb, sequelize.js

```js
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  Points: {
    type: DataTypes.NUMBER,
    defaultValue: 0,
    allowNull: false
  },
  UserId: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: true
  }
}, 
{
  sequelize,
  modelName: 'User',
  tableName: 'Points'
});
User.sync()
```

This code chucks out a MariaDB error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `UserId` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '', `createdAt` DATETIME NO...' at line 1
```

Could someone help please? I am quite new to this sort of thing so I wouldn't really know. Thanks!

Comment: Since you are using MariaDB (which version?), did you install and require the proper `mariadb` driver and not the `mysql2` driver?